# Google spreadsheet to html and filtering function thru web apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Recently, my company changed office ware to G Suite from MS office. To organize the spreadsheet data, i am using the web apps. So I am newbie here.

I am exporting the spreadsheet to html and trying to make filter function but it doesn't work well. Maybe there is some clear steps to cleansing the codes. So i am here to have your supports. Please advise.

**Q1)** There might be the simple way however i don know how to integrate the filter function with the parsed data.

**Q2)** The date column should be changed to text to import html. Is there any other way to display the date column?

**Q3)** Is there any way to show the page number in the html page if there is long thread?

```js
 <script>
  var rows = [];
  var inputFilter = document.getElementById('filter');
  var ulNames = document.getElementById('names');
  
  function load() {
     google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
       rows = response.map(function(r) {
        return r[0] + r [1] + r [2] + r [3] + r [4];
       }); 
       
       ulNames.innerHTML = rows.map(function(row) {
        return '<li>' + row + '</li>';
      }).join('');
      
      inputFilter.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
        var filter = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();
        var filteredArray = rows.filter(function(row) {
         return row.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
        });
      
       ulNames.innerHTML = filteredArray.map(function(row) {
        return '<li>' + row + '</li>';
      }).join('');
      });
      
     })
     .getData();

  }
 load();  

</script>
```

Comment: You want to filter your values based on what? Please add an example spreadsheet and explain the way you want to filter and output your sheet data in the table.

Comment: I would filter all the column however i dont know how to connect filtered one with DOM. The sample spreadsheet link is following https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FXSdUy5OWabCyD_Xu95SCXptdWgCVf99GZqclf2KfIE/edit#gid=0

Comment: I don't understand how you want to filter.

Comment: i mean i want use map function to filtered one and put in the table. but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: I just solve the problem..i correct the map function and works.. However the date property and page function could be take long...